# Does sharepoint push the document changes?

Tags: document

Please suggest if sharepoint does push the information about the changes in a document to a jsp page? Also please share on how to implement the same?

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement Event Handler on the document library. In the event handler, that fires when document is added/modified, you an do whatever required in order to push these changes outside SharePoint.